# Верстка landing page. Сложный фон

Tags: html, css

Всем привет! Недавно начал обучаться верстке сайтов. Как реализовать такого рода фон? Чтобы это был не просто рисунок, а максимально адаптивный фон. Буду благодарен за любые подсказки.
[image: макет сайта]

Comment: Фон у тебя в любом случае будет картинкой. Сверстай как можешь и уже потом смотри и думай как улучшить. Поиграйся с background-position и background-size.

Comment: @Profesor08, почему фон должен быть картинкой? Фоном должен быть только серый фон, а картинки и статьи - нет.

Comment: @Profesor08 сделал часть фона через linear-gradient. А как реализовать серые и фиолетовые мазки на фоне ? И фотографии: их реализовывать в рамках фона или вставить в div-ы и уже с помощью них позиционировать?